# Why openssl can't decode the string encoded by base64_encode function of php?

Tags: php, c, openssl, base64

I want to base64 encode a string, and decode it in C language with `OpenSSL` api.
I encoded in `php` like that:

```
<?php 
echo base64_encode("aaa");
?>

result is "YWFh"
```

Then decode it in `C` like that:

```
int base64_decode(char *str,int str_len,char *decode,int decode_buffer_len){
    int len=0;
    BIO *b64,*bmem;
    b64=BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem=BIO_new_mem_buf(str,str_len);
    bmem=BIO_push(b64,bmem);
    len=BIO_read(bmem,decode,str_len);
    decode[len]=0;
    BIO_free_all(bmem);
    return 0;
}

result is NULL, nothing decoded.
```

Can't decode the string encoded before.

I tried to use these command lines to test:

```
$echo "aaa" | openssl enc -base64 
output: YWFhCg==

$echo "YWFhCg==" | openssl enc -base64 -d
output: aaa
```

What's the difference between base64_encode in `php` and `openssl`?What causes this?

Comment: "YWFhCg==" is "aaa\n"

Comment: But why can't my `C` code decode it?

Comment: So pipping a string to openssl seems to add a newline character

Comment: Even I use a very long string, It's different all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL)` after the BIO_new() call to tell OpenSSL that all the input appears in a single line without newline.